# Magento 2.3 don't show products if price is 0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-list, product-prices

Is there a way to hide products that have the price at 0?

I tried with this Plugin but it shows the same all the products even those at price 0.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

/**
 * Class ListProductPlugin
 */
class ListProductPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param ListProduct $subject
     * @param AbstractCollection $resultCollection
     * @return AbstractCollection
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetLoadedProductCollection(
        ListProduct $subject,
        AbstractCollection $resultCollection
    ) {
        $resultCollection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $resultCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['gt' => 0]);

        return $resultCollection;
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `eq` like below code

```
$resultCollection->addAttributeToFilter('price', ['eq' => 0]);
```

**Hope it Helps.**